# Using my Google Geocoding API key with Python geocoder

Tags: python, google-maps, pandas, google-geocoding-api

I'm a beginner at Python and I've been working to geocode a database using Pandas and Geocoder on Jupyter.

Since the df is a little long (around 3000 rows), I'd like to use Google's Geocoding API.

I've already created a free key, but I have no idea what I'm supposed to do with it. Help?

By the way, my code looks like this:

```
import geocoder
import pandas as pd

geo = geocoder

df=pd.read_excel('hsp2.xlsx')

df['Coordinates']=df['Address'].apply(geo.google).apply(lambda x: x.latlng if x != None else None)

df.to_csv('output.csv', sep='|', encoding='iso8859_15')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set the environment variable *before* you import `geocoder`:

```
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_API_KEY"] = "api_key_from_google_cloud_platform"

import geocoder

geo = geocoder.google(address)
latlong = geo.latlng
```

**Note:**

As Murmel mentioned in the comments, environment variables containing keys (and in general) should not be set inside of your code.
If you are deploying this somewhere then set up enviroment variables in your configuration file.  Or even better, as a secret in something like Kubernetes.

Else set the environment variable in bash with
`export GOOGLE_API_KEY=api_key_from_google_cloud_platform`

Comment: As I wrote in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48190942/1885518), I think your answer somehow misuses the concept of providing the API KEY. According to the [docs](http://geocoder.readthedocs.io/providers/Google.html#environment-variables), the env variable is meant to be used for "`[...] mak[ing] sure your API key is stored safely on your computer, you can define that API key using your system’s environment variables.`" Thus, I think it would be good to at least mention this or describe how to do this not within python code.

Comment: That's a bit lame to have to import the key before importing the lib..

Answer (score 4):

Basically there are 2 options:

- passing the API KEY as environment variable:

  ```
  GOOGLE_API_KEY=YOUR-API-KEY-HERE  python your_program.py
  ```
- passing the API KEY as argument:

  ```
  geocoder.google('some address', key='YOUR-API-KEY-HERE')
  ```

---

**Details**

1. You are using the python library called [geocoder](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geocoder), which itself is a wrapper around multiple geocoding services.
2. If you look at the [pypi page of geocoder](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geocoder), you can (ignoring the rendering problems) find the [docs](http://geocoder.readthedocs.io/) for geocoder. In your case you probably want to have a look at the [Google related part of the docs](http://geocoder.readthedocs.io/providers/Google.html#geocoding).
3. For basic usage this seams to work even without an API KEY, but you can specify one using 2 variants:

   - [Environment variable](http://geocoder.readthedocs.io/providers/Google.html#environment-variables): Like [Roman already showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45508192/1885518). This approach is meant to be used to not have the *API KEY* in code - for security reasons. (Probably you want to upload your code into a public repository, but without exposing your *API KEY* to everyone.)
   - ["Key" parameter:](http://geocoder.readthedocs.io/providers/Google.html#parameters) You can also provide your *API KEY* by specifying it using the `key` parameter, like:

     ```
     geocoder.google('some address', key='YOUR-API-KEY-HERE')
     ```

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with [Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45508192/1885518) answer. You can use that and it is working. I am bit afraid if I use geocoder in loop then google will definately block my ip address ,so I go through git hub code and found that geocoder get google api key from `os.environ.get('GOOGLE_API_KEY')`. You can see that in the picture:

[image: here]

Comment: Hm not quite sure, what you are trying to say? It is more a comment on Roman's answer, isn't it?
Meta: Instead of linking to Roman's profile, I would recommend you tolink to his actual answer. Furthermore, instead of posting an image of the code, simply copy and paste the code and provide the link to the github for further reference is in general a better approach.