# Always getting None values when using Python Geocoder

Tags: python

Im using Python's `geocoder` lib , and Im trying to find city names based on lat and lng. The problem is that I always get `None` values, any ideas why?

import geocoder

```
lat = 44.0207472303
lng = 20.9033038427
print(lat, lng)

city_name = geocoder.google([lat, lng], method = 'reverse')
city_name = str(city_name.city)

print(city_name) #None
```

Comment: Do you have API key for the API ?

Comment: No, I did not know what I need that. How can I get that?

Comment: Here you go https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#get-a-key

Comment: Geocoder documentation says that It does not requires api key. Also I have saw some codes on this website that work without api

Comment: This question is actually a duplicate of [Using my Google Geocoding API key with Python geocoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336763/using-my-google-geocoding-api-key-with-python-geocoder).

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to use Google's [geocoding API](https://geocoder.readthedocs.io/providers/Google.html) with [gecoder](https://geocoder.readthedocs.io/), you need to have the Google API keys set in the environment variables. See [here](https://geocoder.readthedocs.io/providers/Google.html#environment-variables).

To get the Geocoding API keys, you must first activate the API in the Google Cloud Platform Console and obtain the proper authentication credentials. You can get API credentials here,

**https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/#get-started**

After getting the API key, you need to add the following code in order to use it.

```
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_API_KEY"] = "API_KEY"
```

[Source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#get-a-key)

Comment: um, is this free?